# Handling PFErrorCode on swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Will I started to code a sign up view controller with Swift and Parse.
the sign up has a checking if username or email are taken in parse client

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
        query.whereKey("email", equalTo: email)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
        newUser.signUpInBackground{(success, error) -> Void in

            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved scores.")


            if success {
                // Do something with the found objects


                let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Register complated", message: "You've been registered.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

                    alertMessage.addAction(okAction)
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)



            }

                // Log details of the failure
                // username is exists
            else  {

                if PFErrorCode.errorUsernameTaken.rawValue == 202 {

                    print ("Username is exists")
                }

                else if PFErrorCode.errorUserEmailTaken.rawValue == 203 {
                    print ("E-mail is exists")


                }

            }
```

When I tried to write an existing e-mail or password the output in the console didn't show the print () the same what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you aren't comparing the error's code but instead a fixed number with different PFErrorCodes.

```
/// Your code
if let error = error, error._code == PFErrorCode.errorUsernameTaken.rawValue {
    print ("Username is exists")
} else if let error = error, error._code == PFErrorCode.errorUserEmailTaken.rawValue {
    print ("E-mail is exists")
}
```

Also, email is unique in Parse so you should consider using *getFirstObjectInBackground* instead of *findObjectsInBackground*. And use *PFUser.query()* instead of _PFQuery(className:"*User")*.

Comment: Hey nts, I copied the extension inside inaction button, and there some error pop in the compiler.

Comment: Paste the extension in another file (e.g: PFErrorCode+Equatable)

Comment: Hey nts, I tried extension that you wrote and I got three error message. Could you be more specific where should I put the extension in where?

Comment: The extension works fine since I've been using it for a while. First things first, have you added the proper imports ?. Second, paste the error messages. Answer updated with solution that doesn't need the extension.